# Automatically filling certain parameters in an html file on hosted server with node js

Tags: html, node.js

I'm working on a project in which I have a simple web server hosted with node.js (see code below) and I want to be able to dynamically load the code form html files and modify them each time someone makes a request. I've already putted some marker in my code `${likeThis}` and I just need the code to put a string in the right place.

Here is my server code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
})

app.listen(8080);
});
```

And here is an example page in which I want to change the value `${sampleText}` with the plain text "hello world!!!":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<title>Titler</title>
</head>
<body>
${sampleText}
</body>
```

Mind that there might be more of the same or different kind of value all over the html page.

On the user side I'd expect this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<title>Titler</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world!!!
</body>
```

Comment: You use `serve-static`. As its name implies that module is for serving static objects (images? style sheets?), not dynamic objects like you specify. I suggest you read about `express` and `pug` for delivering dynamic pages.

Comment: ok, i read about it a bit, but now i'm wondering how i will be able to import my html pages and modify them at the same time, i will modify the question .  .  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of work(very flew actualy) i monaged to make this function that allows me to find the strings and replace them with the correct text, i will publish it hoping someone else in the future migth need it:

```
function substituteString(input, stringToChange, substitute) {
    var n = 0;
    while (true) {
        n = input.indexOf(stringToChange, n);
        if (n == -1) { break; } else {
            input = input.replace(stringToChange ,substitute);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Easier than i was thinking

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to use live data in pages returned from express. All of them utilize a "template" into which you inject "data". These include:

- [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)
- [mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache)
- [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars)

Another option would be to use NodeJS/ES6 template strings, such as:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Text to insert into template
const sampleText = 'hello world!!!'

// Template to accept sampleText
const result = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Titler</title>
</head>
<body>
  ${sampleText}
</body>
</html>
`

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send(result);
})

app.listen(8080);
```

Backticks ("`") are used to define template strings in Node where "${expression}" is used to insert any evaluable JavaScript expression into a template, like:

```
const result = `The contents of file ${filepath} are: ${fs.readFileSync(filepath).toString()}`
```

For more information, see [Using Template Engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)
and for an exhaustive list of template engines that work "out of the box" with Express see [Template Engines](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html)

Answer (score 0):

i ll illustrate with Mustache, you need webpack for communication between front-side and web-server, but since webpack is headache i ll use mustache CDN.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="message"></div>
//we are gonna render the message into this div tag.
//this is a javascript code


//make sure script tags are at the bottom
<script id="message-template" type="text/html">
      <div class="message">
          {{message}} . //yes double curly brackets
      </div>  
    </script>
   //CDN link, Mustache pack files are stored here and we import from there
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>
 //for src add path of index.js in your app
<script src="./index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
//select the div that you wanna place the message
const $message = document.querySelector("#messages");

//select the script tag in 
const messageTemplate = document.querySelector("#message-template").innerHTML;


const html = Mustache.render(messageTemplate, {
    //I hardcoded the message here, but as you learn, you will catch a dynamic data, put it here and display in your html page
    message:"hello world",
  });
  $message.innerHTML(html);
```